# Adding VM Argument Format Using Eclipse

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

I'm trying to add or set the VM Argument for my dll file but I'm stuck on what format I should use.

Here is the format:
-Djava.library.path="${workspace_loc:project}\lib;${env_var:PATH}"

Djna.library.path=${workspace_loc:/C:\Tess4j\lib}/dlls/win-32x86-64

Here is the location of my dll file or the path to the DLL file of the library:

C:\Tess4j\lib\win32-x86-64

Here is my file:
libtesseract3051.dll

Should I format It like this;

Djava.library.path=${workspace_loc:/C:\Tess4j\lib}/dlls/win-32x86-64

OR

Djna.library.path=${workspace_loc:/C:\Tess4j\lib}/dlls/win-32x86-64

Comment: There is no sense in using a variable (`workspace_loc`) and then specifying an unrelated absolute path (`C:\Tess4j\lib`). Either you specify an absolute path or you specify a resource relative to a variable.

Comment: So it should be my project name and the path the my dll file like this:
Djna.library.path=${workspace_loc:/ocr-tess4j-project}/dlls/win-32x86-64